# VBA listview subitems

Tags: vba, excel

How can I save value to a selected item on listview from a multiple textbox, so that whenever I move to another value on listbox and then get back to the previous value, all of the multiple textbox will populate the saved inputs in textbox.

Comment: I don't understand this question. What is "listview from a multiple textbox"?

Comment: I mean is how will I save values on textbox1,2 and 3, to a selected value on listview. Sorry for my question.

Comment: You might create an array `Arr(1 To 3)` where 3 is the number of textboxes you want to store the values for. Assign the value of TextBox1 to Arr(1), Arr(2)=TextBox2.Value, Arr(3)=TextBox(3) etc. Reverse the process to assign the textboxes the values stored in the array, e.g. `TextBox1.Value = Arr(1)`, `TextBox2.Value = Arr(2)` etc.

Comment: Thanks for this, but how about if I have multiple value on listview having the same scenario which is it will save multiple value of textbox to a certain selected value on listview. Can you give an example of your code regarding this scenario? Just to help me understand the flow

Comment: Any sample code you tried might help...

Comment: A ListBox has the `Selected` collection which works similar to the Arr() described above. The collection has elements from 1 to the number items in your list (ListCount) and each element holds the value of either `True` (meaning it is selected) or `False`. To restore a ListBox to a particular setting use the code like `ListBox1.Selected(1) = True`. You can construct a loop to address all selections.